# Not able to get current cursor position in C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, ncurses

I'm using `ncurses` to make a simple GUI for my C++ project.
I'm just trying to get cursor position when the user clicks with the mouse but I always get the same output `(0,0)`, here's the code:

```cpp
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    char c;

    initscr();
    clear();
    noecho();
    mousemask(ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS, NULL);

    while(1)
    {
        c = getch();
        if(c == BUTTON1_CLICKED)
        {
            getyx(stdscr, x, y);
            printw("POS(%d,%d)\n", x, y);
            refresh();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program doesn't print anything until I click with the mouse on the terminal, but the coordinates are always the same `(0,0)`, even if the cursor position changes.
Does someone know how can I solve this?

Comment: ncurses is for creating TUI, not GUI

Comment: Yeah sorry, I've wrote it in a bad way

Answer (score 4):

This

```
getyx(stdscr,x,y);
```

only returns the coordinates in the *virtual* screen which your program has set.  If you want to get the coordinates at which you click the mouse, you'll have to use different functions (see [`getmouse`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_mouse.3x.html#h3-getmouse), which is only relevant if [`getch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Predefined-key-codes) returns **`KEY_MOUSE`**).

Comment: Thank you so much, I just solved this problem with your help, thank to you! :)